# Shortcut for Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Based on this: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/nodejs, I tried running:

```
code .
```

I have Visual Studio Code on my machine. How is that alias created?

Comment: It's on your path, try `echo %PATH%`.

Comment: Are you on Windows, Linux or OSX?